# wp_get_attachment_link() add rel attribute if the link points to direct image

Tags: images, attachments, gallery

I'm using filter like this to add `rel` attribute in `wp_get_attachment_link()`

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'sant_prettyadd'); 
function sant_prettyadd ($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("/<a/","<a rel=\"prettyPhoto[slides]\"",$content,1);
    return $content;
}
```

The above filter working fine except it adds the attribute even if the `href` points to attachment page.

I mean I want to add `rel` attribute only if the link points to direct image and not attachment page.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_link', 'sant_prettyadd', 10, 6);

function sant_prettyadd ($content, $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text) {
    if ($permalink) {
    return $content;    
    }
    $content = preg_replace("/<a/","<a rel=\"prettyPhoto[slides]\"",$content,1);
    return $content;
}
```

### Update:

function sant_prettyadd checks permalink argument.

if the `permalink = true` then it returns the content as it is.

if the `permalink = false` then it skips to the next line and replace the `<a` with `<a rel="prettyPhoto[slides]"` and then returns the content.

Comment: For the benefit of future generations, explain what this code does ツ ◎ܫ◎

Comment: @brasofilo Updated my answer